# rails4, handling model with merge multi table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

My Rails proejct using SMS Service...

and sms service make new table monthly named likes **MMS_201410**, **MMS_201411**, **MMS_201412**

and waiting table is **MMS_List**

how to merge multi table like one model.

I wanna listing one index page using kaminari

```
@mm = MergeMms.page(params[:page]).per(30)
```

is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a view in your database that unions the rows from tables together...

```
CREATE VIEW MMS_List AS
SELECT * FROM MMS_201412
UNION ALL
SELECT * FROM MMS_201411
...
```

Mostly, that solution sucks because you have to update the view every time a new MMS table appears (but that could be solved with a cron job). You could solve it the same way in Ruby by performing the `SELECT` and `UNION` but I would not recommend it since who knows what the query planner would do when you're attempting to page across `UNION`s.

Perhaps the easiest solution is to write a cron job that attempts to query a table for the current month and if its present and not previously processed, it `INSERTS` all of the rows from the table into your `MMS_List` table (`SELECT * FROM new_table INSERT INTO MMS_List` or something like that). Then insert a row into some other table (let's call it `MMS_already_processed`) that tracks which tables have been processed so you don't duplicate insert records. You'd need to ensure that the query asking for data from a newly discovered table can get an exclusive read lock to that table so you don't read only some of the rows (e.g., if your cron job ran while a new table was in the process of being created and only some of the data had been inserted at that time).

This is a problem that you should try and solve at the data tier first.

Comment: Thx your advice :)  I'll try union table... @cfeduke